# @Injectable Service not transferring to Component in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am attempting to create an Observable from an HTTP Get request in my app.services.ts file and have it move data between my two controllers.

I have the variable that I want defined in my controller and I have injected the service to the controller's constructor without any errors, but when I log the variable to the console when my app loads I get `undefined`.

app.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getContacts() {
    return this._http.get('assets/api/contacts.json')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: any[]; <--  //this is where I defined my variable 
  errorMessage: string;


  constructor (private _apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(){ this.getContacts();
    console.log(this.contacts);   <-- //This is where I get undefined
  }

  getContacts() {
    this._apiService.getContacts()
    .subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts,
     error => this.errorMessage = error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got undefined because of `contacts` was declared but not initialized and the service is async, it's not ready when you print it out.You can add

```
 getContacts() {
    this._apiService.getContacts()
    .subscribe(
      (contacts) => {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        console.log(this.contacts);  // add it here
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
      }
    }
```